# can't scrap from aliexpress (selector get no data)

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I try to scrap from `aliexpress` using the request
but when getting a selector from HTML to get data the response is none or no data
Here code :

```
cats_list = []
for cat in cats:
    cat_link = list(cat.absolute_links)[0]
    cat_name = cat.text
    cat_dict ={"name":cat_name , "link" :cat_link}
    cats_list.append(cat_dict)
print(cats_list)   \\Here success to get all category \\

r= await asession.get(cats_list[0]['link'])
await r.html.arender(sleep=10)
\\selector\\
 **prodcts = r.html.find("#card-list > a:nth-child(9) > div.manhattan--content--1KpBbUi")** \\nothing response
print(prodcts)
```

image for code:

[image]

Comment: What's in `r`? Maybe you will redirected by aliexpress, I can image that they don't want to be crawled. In this case they return another website.